# Downloading file from url ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

Is it possible to download a pdf from given url and save it to a server using ColdFusion?
I am looking for a method similar to a  `file_put_contents()` in php and I couldn't find anything in the Adobe documentation.
Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can use the [`cfhttp`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ffc.html) tag to download a document from a URL and save it to a file:

Specifically, you'll do something like:

```
<cfhttp method="get" url="#fileURL#" path="#filePath#" file="#fileName#" />
```